# Cannot run script/Java program on Raspberry Pi 3B boot

Tags: java, linux, boot

I'm simply trying to make a program run when the Raspberry boots up. The idea being it runs, so there is no need for a mouse/keyboard to manually start the program.

I've read forum after forum on how to run a script on boot on a Raspberry Pi.  I feel like I've exhausted every method.

I have tried:

1. scheduling a cronjob

`sudo crontab -e` and then added the code

`@reboot /file/path/myscript/`

2. Putting my progam in the /etc/init.d/ folder and updating it in the boot sequence.

file moved to `/etc/init.d/myscript/`

make executable  `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/myscript/`

register script `sudo update-rc.d defaults`

3. Adding it to the .bashrc folder in the `/pi` directory

navigated to `/home/pi/.bashrc/`

added `./myscript/` to the file.

None of these have worked for me, whereas for everyone else on those forums, it seems to have solve their problem.  Is there something I'm missing from any of these methods?

Comment: You might have more luck on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com with this question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.